# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Error in Angular 4 Application

Tags: html, forms, angular, typescript

I have a HTML that displays some elements that it gets from the database: Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="home-page">
  <div class="container page">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-10">
        <h2>Search</h2>
        <hr>
        <form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && emptyAndBindNew(); searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Type--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
                {{ powerPlantType }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Status--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
                {{ powerPlantStatus }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
            <button type="button" (click)="resetForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div>

          <ul id="infinite-scroller" appInfiniteScroller scrollPerecnt="70" [immediateCallback]="true" [scrollCallback]="scrollCallback">
            <li *ngFor="let powerPlant of powerPlants">{{powerPlant.powerPlantName}}</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can see I'm calling 2 different functions in my Typescript which is as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PowerPlantService, UserService } from '../shared';
import { User } from '../shared/models/user.model';
import { PowerPlant } from '../shared/models/powerplant.model';
import {PowerPlantSearchParams} from '../shared/models/powerplantsearchparams.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Represents the PowerPlantTypes
  powerPlantTypes = ['RampUpType', 'OnOffType'];
  // Represents the status of a PowerPlant
  powerPlantStatuses = ['Active & Disabled', 'Active', 'Disabled'];
  // Represents the search form
  model: any = {};
  // represents the list of PowerPlant data
  powerPlants: PowerPlant[] = [];
  scrollCallback;

  currentPage = 1;

  // Indicates if the searchButton was clicked or not!
  isSearchButtonClicked = false;

  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {
    // this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    // Set the initial values for the drop down fields in the UI
    this.resetForm();

    this.scrollCallback = this.searchPowerPlants.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  resetForm() {
    this.model.powerPlantOrg = '';
    this.model.powerPlantName = '';
    this.model.powerPlantType = '';
    this.model.powerPlantStatus = '';
  }

  emptyAndBindNew() {
    this.isSearchButtonClicked = true;
  }

  searchPowerPlants() {
    if (this.isSearchButtonClicked === true) {
      this.isSearchButtonClicked = false;
      // Reset the old entries
      this.powerPlants = [];
      this.currentPage = 1;
      this.searchPowerPlants();
    } else {
      alert('page number is ' + this.currentPage);
      const powerPlantSearchParams = new PowerPlantSearchParams(
        this.model.powerPlantType,
        this.model.powerPlantOrg,
        this.model.powerPlantName,
        this.model.powerPlantStatus);

      return this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams, this.currentPage).do(this.processData);
    }
  }

  private processData = (newPowerPlants) => {
    this.currentPage++;
    // this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants.json());
    this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants);
  }
}
```

I get a very strange error in my Angular application:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''.
```

The error happens in this line:

```
        <li *ngFor="let powerPlant of powerPlants">{{powerPlant.powerPlantName}}</li>
```

What is the problem with my piece of code and how to get rid of this error: Here is what the whole thing is about!

1. The user is presented with a Search form where he can enter his different search criteria
2. When the user clicks Search button, I call a REST API backend and fetch some data (I limit the fetch to 10 entries).
3. When the user scrolls down on the result entries, I load him additional 10 entries and this keeps going on as long as I can find more data.
4. Now if the user wishes to search for some other criteria, he enters again the search fields and submits the form.
5. When the form is submitted, I have to reset all the old search results and populate the new entries that I get from the backend REST API!

The above code does that, but it runs into error after I do point number 4! Any ideas? Here is a screenshot of the error that I face!

EDIT: The PowerPlantsService contains the following method:

```
private generateData() {
    const powerPlantArray: PowerPlant[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        const p: PowerPlant = {
          powerPlantId: i,
          powerPlantName: `PowerPlant ${i}`,
          minPower: 100,
          maxPower: 200,
          powerPlantType: 'OnOffType'
        };
        powerPlantArray.push(p);
      } else {
        const p: PowerPlant = {
          powerPlantId: i,
          powerPlantName: `PowerPlant ${i}`,
          minPower: 100,
          maxPower: 200,
          powerPlantType: 'RampUpType',
          rampPowerRate: 10,
          rampRateInSeconds: 2
        };
        powerPlantArray.concat(p);
      }
    }
    return powerPlantArray;
  }

  searchPowerPlants(searchParams: PowerPlantSearchParams, page: number): Observable<any> {
    const params: string[] = [];
    // pageNumber is mandatory
    if (page) {
      params.push(`page=${page}`);
    } else {
      params.push(`page=1`);
    }
    // All the other fields are optional
    if (searchParams.powerPlantStatus === 'Active') {
      params.push(`onlyActive=true`);
    } else if (searchParams.powerPlantStatus === 'Disabled') {
      params.push(`onlyActive=false`);
    }
    if (searchParams.powerPlantType) {
      params.push(`powerPlantType=${searchParams.powerPlantType}`);
    }
    if (searchParams.powerPlantOrg) {
      params.push(`org=${searchParams.powerPlantOrg}`);
    }
    if (searchParams.powerPlantName) {
      params.push(`name=${searchParams.powerPlantName}`);
    }
    // return this.apiService.get(`${this.allPowerPlantsURL}?${params.join('&')}`);
    return Observable.of(this.generateData());
  }
```

[image]

Comment: you should read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4). It explains the error in depth. If after reading the article you still have questions you can create a plunker that reproduces the problem and show it here

Comment: I understand the article, but I do not understand where my code is different such that it throws this error! Like you explain in your article, I do not have child components, so I could not solve my problem just by reading through the article!

Comment: okay, then create a plunker/stackblitz demo that shows the error, I'll take a look

Comment: That is a huge project set of files and seems plnkr or stackblitz does not support import of projects from my GitHub: github.com/joesan/plant-simulator-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather guessing your error comes from the last line of your last function. Could you try this instead ?

```
this.setTimeout(() => this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants));
```

**EDIT** In your service, replace the `const powerPlantArray` with a `let powerPlantArray` :

```
private generateData() {
  let powerPlantArray: PowerPlant[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      const p: PowerPlant = {
        powerPlantId: i,
        powerPlantName: `PowerPlant ${i}`,
        minPower: 100,
        maxPower: 200,
        powerPlantType: 'OnOffType'
      };
      powerPlantArray.push(p);
    } else {
      const p: PowerPlant = {
        powerPlantId: i,
        powerPlantName: `PowerPlant ${i}`,
        minPower: 100,
        maxPower: 200,
        powerPlantType: 'RampUpType',
        rampPowerRate: 10,
        rampRateInSeconds: 2
      };
      powerPlantArray.concat(p);
    }
  }
  return powerPlantArray;
}
```

Comment: Second option alone does not work! I get the same error as I posted above!

Comment: Where do I put the setTimeout?

Comment: You replace the reset form call in your constructor with the set timeout

Comment: Nope it complaints that the setTimeout cannot be found!

Comment: Woops I'm sorry, it's setTimeout only, delete the "this" in front of it !

Comment: Still the same problem! Does not work with either of your options or even both!

Comment: Can you take a look at the description - Especially where I describe in points 1 to 5. I effectively want to acheive that. Can you propose an alternative solution?

Comment: Oh I see. Try using the setTimeout in your last line of code (wrap `this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants); }` with it)

Comment: What is that setTimeout doing? Could you edit your answer?

Comment: I wanted to solve it before explaining but here we go : your problems comes from the fact that you change a variable value after it has been checked by angular. The setTimeout is here to tell angular to wait for his cycle to finish before assigning a new value to your variable. And I will try to edit it but wait a minute, I'm on phone !

Comment: Let me give it a try and post the result!

Comment: It kind of got rid of the problem by clearing the old entries, but when I hit the Search button again, I do not see the list of new entries appear

Comment: There is no error at all, but the whole div area is empty!

Comment: And if you do a console log in the set timeout, is your data here ?

Comment: Hmm... strange... the data is not there... but it cannot be the case as I'm delivering just static data instead of using an actual backend! I have updated my post with the PowerPlantService... Please take a look!

Comment: Well, as I told you I'm on phone, but try concatening hard data to your array, and see if the solution I gave works, then if it does, focus on your lack of data problem!

Comment: I can't see where the problem is! I will try my best, but honestly it is confusing!

Comment: If you can wait until tomorrow I'll help you, sorry !

Comment: No worries! Here is the entire codebase: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator-ui

Comment: I light have found it anyways : in your service, first line, you declare a constant. Try declaring a variable with `let` ?

Comment: Where do you mean? Could you please tell me which line?

Comment: At the very last line of the code of your component you posted in this question !

Comment: You have to be a bit specific here. The very last line now is this one:     setTimeout(() => this.powerPlants = this.powerPlants.concat(newPowerPlants));

Comment: Sorry I've lost myself, hard time on phone yesterday ... See my edit and try it !

Comment: Nope! It still does not work! After hitting the search button there are no results anymore!

Comment: And does your service return the data ? Try using a console log just before the return and see if the data is returned

Comment: I had an alert in my searchPowerPlants() method and I can see that the data array is there. But this array is not pushed into the processData method! So I guess there is something fundamentally wrong with using the bind mechanism!

Comment: If you look at my latest codebase, I have added the alerts and if you can manage to get a local copy of the code and run it on your machine, I guess you might be able to help me better!

Comment: I can't either, locked computers at work :/ And in your processData function, into your component, do you have the data ?

Comment: Nope! that is the whole reason behind the problem. The data is there until the call to the processData function and is somehow lost. I have an alert inside the processData and this alert is not getting hit!

Comment: Well then, you've found your problem ! Maybe make another question here to solve it ? This is one is getting a bit long ahah